# MYSQL Error #1064 - How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

***Error***

SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 06/02/2015 WHERE `ID` = '1')
    INSERT INTO 06/02/2015 SET `text` = '[22:37:44] test'
ELSE
    CREATE TABLE `06/02/2015` (`ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, `text` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '', PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
    INSERT INTO `06/02/2015` SET `text` = '[22:37:44] test'
```

MySQL said:

```
#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM 06/02/2015 WHERE `ID` = '1')
    INSERT INTO 06/02/2015 S' Ã  la ligne 1
```

How to fix it?
And I did it right?

Comment: `if` as a statement only works in code blocks, such as in stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  So, if this is not in a code block, then it is not correct.

Comment: Since when is `06/02/2015` anywhere **CLOSE** to being a valid table name, or even a valid mysql date? You have `select * from 06/02/2015`, which would be doing DIVISION and be equiavlent to `select * from 0.0014895...`

Comment: I use Google Translate so if you can write a little more simply ...
Sorry about that and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
06/02/2015
```

This snippet is invalid because this is not a valid table name.

Comment: @rick6 #1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `ID` = '1')
    INSERT INTO `test` SET `text' Ã  la ligne 1